How can I change a vertex in 'boost::geometry::polygon'?
I am using the following code to get the vertices from a boost::geometry::polygon:
using namespace boost::geometry;
using PointType = model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using PolygonType = model::polygon<PointType, false>;   // clockwise ordering

PolygonType poly;
// set several vertices here
for(auto pos = 0; pos < num_points(poly); ++pos) {
    PointType pt = poly.outer()[pos];
    // do something with the point here
}   

However, I can't find an easy way to set the values of a specific point in the polygon. The following doesn't work:
PointType new_pt{3, 3};
poly.outer()[pos] = new_pt;

What am I doing wrong?
See my comment below - this DOES work

“doesn’t work” - what is the problem you’re actually seeing?

My apologies - "doesn't work" is indeed not at all helpful at finding a solution! And it turns out I am wrong: poly.outer()[pos] = new_pt does indeed set the value of the point at pos. I had overlooked another part of my code that cleared the polygon of points before reaching the snippet I show above. Sorry!

We can’t really know what type of problem you run into. So let me illustrate how I’d do this - and that works:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using PointType = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>;
using PolygonType = bg::model::polygon<PointType, false>;   // clockwise ordering

int main ()
{
  PolygonType poly;
  bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0))", poly);

  auto num_points = poly.outer().size();
  PointType const shift(100,100);

  for (auto pos = 0ul; pos < num_points; ++pos)
    {
      PointType pt = poly.outer ()[pos];
      // do something with the point here
      bg::add_point(pt, shift);
      poly.outer ()[pos] = pt;
    }
  std::cout << "first: " << bg::wkt(poly) << "\n";

That prints the shifted rectangle. But it could be simpler:
  // simpler
  for (auto pos = 0ul; pos < num_points; ++pos)
      bg::add_point(poly.outer ()[pos], shift);
  std::cout << "second: " << bg::wkt(poly) << "\n";

Or indeed much simpler
  // even simpler
  for (auto& pt: poly.outer())
    bg::add_point(pt, shift);
  std::cout << "third: " << bg::wkt(poly) << "\n";

Last but not least, there’s a more idiomatic way to operate on any BG geometry. This has the advantage that it will actually correctly work on inner rings of your polygon if they are present:
  bg::for_each_point(poly, [shift](auto& pt) {
    bg::add_point(pt, shift);
  });
  std::cout << "fourth: " << bg::wkt(poly) << "\n";
}

The output on Coliru:
first: POLYGON((100 100,100 101,101 101,101 100,100 100))
second: POLYGON((200 200,200 201,201 201,201 200,200 200))
third: POLYGON((300 300,300 301,301 301,301 300,300 300))
fourth: POLYGON((400 400,400 401,401 401,401 400,400 400))


Thank you for this example - it gives me a much better understanding of the user interface for polygon.

I'd like to ask some followup questions, if you would indulge me, please? 1) How do you add a point to a polygon? e.g. Say I wanted to add a point at (100.5, 101.5) just after (100, 101). How can you do that without re-assigning the entire polygon? 2) How do you delete a point from the polygon? e.g. Having added the point at (100.5, 101.5), how can I delete it without re-assigning the entire polygon? Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.
